# Code conversion from Xcode to Android

Tags: android, xcode, cross-platform, multiplatform

I am currently working on multi platform application. I have coded my app in Xcode. Do I have to rewrite my entire code or is there an easier way? Are there any third party applications which could help address my problem?

Comment: There are projects out there that will do objective-c to java translation, but nothing that will just magically make your app work in Android. I believe the only solution for that is to use a cross-platform library in the first place. Or use something like C++ that can then be implemented in the Android NDK.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the advice.